# Resizable fixed top navigation menu

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive, fixed

I am trying to make a semi-responsive web site project that will be viewed on an ipad. I made an html body with a max width of 800px. This works well enough for my purposes, but I also have a fixed navigation on the top with drop down menus. When the site is over 800px, it works fine, but if it scales below that, e.g to the 768 width when it is viewed vertically on the iPad, part of the menu bar sticks out a little, while the rest of the html scales proportionally with the viewport.

I am hoping the remedy is something simple. I am including a very simplified version of my code below. I removed all of the dropdown menu content since it should just be the container that has to work.

Thanks in advance! :)

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="page">
                <header id="apu_top">some content<img src="images/chapter_cover_images/2x/ch5_apu@2x.png" width="100%"/> 
                </header>
                <main>      
                    <nav id="main_nav_bar_container"> 
                        <div id="main_nav_bar">
                            <div id="main_nav_top_div"> some content </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </main>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #888;
        clear: both;
    }

    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.19em;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: left;
        hyphens: auto;
    }
    #page {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #main_nav_bar_container {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        max-width: 800px;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    #main_nav_bar {
        background-color: #2580B9;
        color: #F3A51D;
        font-size: 1em;
        height: 38px;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #main_nav_top_div  {
        z-index: 10000;
        margin-left: 4%;
    }
```

[image: picture of error at 768 width]

Comment: The body in your sample code doesn't have margin-left and right set to zero (it has margin by default). With the margin it will be pushed to the right. 
Or give the  #main_nav_bar_container a   left: 0; and right: 0; .
But probably that's not what you are looking for here, do you have a screenshot or link?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide us minimal, verifiable, working solution to the above stated problem in sites such as jsfiddle etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in your screenshot I think I see the default margins on the body of 8px and right and left side.

So what you can do is adding a width calculation of 100% minus the 2 * 8px.
Remain the max-width so it will never get bigger than 800px.

```
#main_nav_bar_container {
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 800px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Or instead of the width calc, you could use `left: 8px;` and `right: 8px;` :)